# IE10 and HTML5 audio

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-10

I have a HTML5 audio / JS based sample player which works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE10 (latest one in Win8 dev preview).

Now I have 2 issues:

a) upon rewinding a currently playing sample using

```
  samples[event.b].pause();
  samples[event.b].currentTime = 0;
```

IE10 gives me

SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_STATE_ERR (11)

on the line setting currentTime. What is that supposed to mean?

b) It dislikes WAV samples (won't play anything) .. just can't believe MS doesnt support WAV. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Consider [`Modernizr.audio`](http://modernizr.com/docs/#audio) in the future. Using `.canPlayType`, it will give you better insight into what the *user agent* can accomodate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an IE10 installed, so i can't check myseld. But here is a file format test page to test which formats are supported:

http://textopia.org/androidsoundformats.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! Apparantly, IE10 does not support WAV, and basically only supports Mpeg formats.

Due to lack of pic upload here, see the shots: https://plus.google.com/u/0/104856249853890787243/posts/6AQWLMHSzKP

How can I mark your reply as 1/2 answer ? ;)

Comment: Actually, the use of the unsupported WAV format was the reason for issue a) .. it works for me using mp3.

Comment: Welcome. The 1/2 answer button is really a missing feature! :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that also!
Btw: Chrome/FF will of course play both mp3 and wav versions of samples, but the wav versions seem to have a slighly faster attack rate (can be triggered faster). Its a tiny difference, but with a beat box and trained ear, you can hear it.

Comment: You can use developer tools in IE11 to simulate IE10 or below.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have implemented the  tag properly and if your server supports Specific audio mime type, IE 10 should just work fine without any problem. IE 10 also checks for audio Hardware.

Currently IE Supported Audio Formats are: MP3 and MP4

Please see the output, on hardware check

[image]